# How do you handle the hex prefix without the value (only "0x")?

Tags: solidity, bytes, data-types, integers, hex

First, I'm caling function `foo()` (from another contract) that returns me a `uint` in the form of `bytes`.

Then, I'm using `BytesLib.toUint(foo(), 0)` to retrieve the `uint`.

When the value is supposed to be `1`, foo returns `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`, and `BytesLib.toUint(foo(), 0)` works fine.

When the value is supposed to be `2`, foo returns `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002`, and `BytesLib.toUint(foo(), 0)` works fine.

However, when the value is supposed to be `0`, foo does not return `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

It returns `0x`. And `BytesLib.toUint(foo()), 0)` does not work.

I would like to implement some logic to check if the value of `foo()` equals `0x`. I've tried multiple things:

- `if (foo() == 0x) { //do something else }`
- `if (foo() == "0x") { //do something else }`
- `if (foo() == address(0)) { //do something else }`
- `if (foo() == keccak256(0x)) { //do something else }`

But all of these result in compilation errors.

How should I handle `0x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x` is technically an empty byte array. In Solidity, you can't do direct comparison of bytes (or other dynamic types), so an easy way to check for this is by checking the length of the bytes, e.g. `foo().length == 0`.

```
contract Foo {
  function foo() public returns (bytes memory) {
    return bytes("");
  }
  
  function bar() public returns (bool) {
    return foo().length == 0;
  }
}
```

Calling `foo()` returns an empty byte array (`0x`), and calling `bar()` returns `true` as expected.